# Additioanl attributes to path element of svg

Tags: svg

How to correctly add additional attributes to `path` element of`svg`? The `data-~*` attributes are not allowed.

I need describe each path element to manipulate of displaying of them.

**UPDATED:**
My SVG file:

````
<svg xmlns="..." viewBox="..." xmlns:example="...">
  <path d="..." example:id="123" />
</svg>```
````

Comment: why would you say data- attributes aren't allowed?

Comment: If you're operating in XML rather than HTML then define your own namespace and put whatever you want in it.

Comment: @RobertLongson I working just on SVG file, when added additional namespace to `<svg />` other tags like `<path />` with namespaces attributes are marked as not allowed.

Comment: @RobertLongson Look now

Comment: Looks fine to me. Perhaps your validator is broken.